# Connecting to Azure SQL database with cppconn

Tags: c++, sql, database, azure

I want to connect to my azure SQL database using the cppconn library. Unfortunately I get this error (path is partially blacked out because of privacy reasons) :

```
# ERR: SQLException in ###/Monitor app/src/liteDatabase.cpp(azureTest) on line 38
# ERR: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 104 (MySQL error code: 2013, SQLState: HY000 )
```

I already opened my port using `sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1433 -j ACCEPT`

The code of the method is stated below.

```
 std::cout << std::endl;
  std::string query = "SELECT * FROM azureDatabase.db_accessadmin.signals;";
  std::cout << "Running " << query << std::endl;
  try 
  {
    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;
    sql::Statement *stmt;
    sql::ResultSet *res;
   /* Create a connection */
    driver = get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("###.database.windows.net:1433", "###", "###");
   /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
    con->setSchema("azureDatabase");
    stmt = con->createStatement();
    res = stmt->executeQuery(query);
    while (res->next()) {
     std::cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
   /* Access column data by alias or column name */
     std::cout << res->getString("_message") << std::endl;
     std::cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
   /* Access column data by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
     std::cout << res->getString(1) << std::endl;
   }
   delete res;
   delete stmt;
   delete con;
 } 
 catch (sql::SQLException &e) 
 {
  std::cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
  std::cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line "
  << __LINE__ << std::endl;
  std::cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
  std::cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
  std::cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << std::endl;
}
  std::cout << std::endl;
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Still sounds like a firewall issue. Have you added your IP to the Azure whitelist?

Comment: I have added a to the whitelist. I can fire the query with my node.js application.

Comment: Is it erroring out immediately? Or is it hitting the timeout limit maybe?

Comment: It takes some time so I think it's the timeout

Comment: Maybe start by increasing the timeout and/or a Fiddler (or whatever program you prefer) trace.